# Failed to Insert Data in SQLITE DataBase using Java in Android?

Tags: java, android, insert, sqlite

i am newbie in android here is the table :

```
    private static final String parameterString = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS parameterTable(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,param_type TEXT,cash_code TEXT,param_description TEXT)";
dataBaseAdapterInstance = new DataBaseAdapter(context);
       @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL(parameterString);
    }
private void setHardCodedSpinnerValue()
{
dataBaseAdapterInstance.openToWrite();
final String endUserContractorArray[] = {"End User -With Risk Assessment","End User -Without Risk Assessment", "Contractor" };

String query =  "INSERT  INTO parameterTable(ID,param_type,cash_code,param_description) " +
 "VALUES ('331','"+endUserContractorArray[0]+"','"EUWRA"','"End User With Risk Assessment"');";
dataBaseAdapterInstance.getDatabaseInstance().execSQL(query);
}
```

I am getting error on this line

```
String query =  "INSERT  INTO parameterTable(ID,param_type,cash_code,param_description) " +
 "VALUES ('331','"+endUserContractorArray[0]+"','"EUWRA"','"End User With Risk Assessment"');";
```

These are the hardcode values  **EUWRA"','"End User With Risk Assessment"'**
  dataBaseAdapterInstance has already declared.The error is when i am trying to insert hardcoded Values.Please help me what am i doing wrong ?

Comment: Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens

Comment: this error is due to spaces in hardCoded String how can i resolve this ?

Comment: when i am trying to write these code then there is no error : so please tell me how can i do without taking extra variables :              final String endUserContractorArray[] = {"End User -With Risk Assessment","End User -Without Risk Assessment", "Contractor" };
String a = endUserContractorArray[0];
String b = "EUWRA";
String c="End User With Risk Assessment";
String query =  "INSERT  INTO parameterTable(ID,param_type,cash_code,param_description) " +
 "VALUES ('331','"+a+"','"+b+"','"+c+"');";

Comment: There's an accepted answer already but the problem wasn't made obvious: `"` terminates your string literal in `""` - if you want `"` in a string, escape it as `\"`. The accepted answer just removed the `"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this way [From here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_insert_query.htm)

```
 String query =  "INSERT  INTO parameterTable(ID,param_type,cash_code,param_description) " +
             "VALUES ('331','"+endUserContractorArray[0]+"','EUWRA','End User With Risk Assessment');";
```

Comment: how can i insert dynamic id like this : int id=31+1+i;   
Log.i("id:",""+id); in "id Column"  where "i" is the loop variable

Comment: actually no need to insert id because it is auto-increment and generated by sqlite itself.